# Union function not working on single cell ranges vba

Tags: excel, vba

In this code, I am attempting to build a range cell by cell using the union function.

```
Function getColumnFromRowIndices(ByRef ws As Worksheet, columnHeader As String, rowIndices() As Long, ByRef headerCells_byHeader As Dictionary) As range

    Dim gCFRI As range 'function alias
    Dim cL As String: cL = getColumnLetterOfCell(headerCells_byHeader(columnHeader))

    If Not IsEmpty(rowIndices) Then

        Dim rI As Variant: For Each rI In rowIndices

            If gCFRI Is Nothing Then Set gCFRI = ws.range(cL & CLng(rI)) _
            Else Set gCFRI = Union(gCFRI, ws.range(cL & CLng(rI)))

        Next rI

    End If

    Set getColumnFromRowIndices = gCFRI

End function
```

The problem I am having is that the union doesn't build up. When I watch ws.range(cL & CLng(rI)) in the watch window, it lists the new cell I want to add, as expected. But the union reverts to arg1 in this case gCFRI everytime it's called.

What must I do to fix this?

Comment: Your union should work OK, try adding `gCFRI.Address` to watch list and observe it's value in the loop.

Comment: Is *ws* being passed in as a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or the name of a worksheet? For that matter how are you passing in *each* of the parameters, particularly the *rowIndices*?

Comment: user3964075. Thanks you are right I was having an issue with the debugger, it wasn't refreshing the value of gCFRI. I'll use gCFRI.Address which shows that the cells pile up.

Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jeeped. Hi, rowIndices is being passed as a long array, take a look at the function signature (1st line in the code) for the argument types. Specifically ws is being passed as a reference to a worksheet object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:

```
Dim gCFRI As range
```

outside the *UDF* to the top of the module in which the *UDF* resides.  This will allow the range to "remember" its previous value and "build-up" as you require.

Comment: The Range was actually growing as I found out later in the code, but the debugger, in my UDF, was not showing the range growing. I'll use range.Address in the future for cases like this. Thanks again.